# Knockout binding checkbox group

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

I have a checkbox group generated dynamically and I need to bind it to my knockout viewmodel.

Here is my code for the checkbox group:

```
<p>
    <label>Properties</label>
    <span class="formwrapper">
        @{
            foreach (ComboProperty item in this.Model.Properties)
            { 
                @:<input type="checkbox" name="chkproperty" value="@item.PropertyId" /> @item.Name<br/>

                }
        }
    </span>
</p>
```

So here instead of a Radio Button group I can have multiple checkboxes selected. So first need to know how to create my knockout viewmodel in order to manage multiple values and then how to bind it.

I have created this in fiddler for reference. It has the json collection.

http://jsfiddle.net/SSHev/5/

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure what you are trying to accomplish but I've updated your jsFiddle in order to make it work:

http://jsfiddle.net/SSHev/11/

When you have a multiple checkboxes that are related, you have a multiple choice input. In Knockout, such an input can be mapped to an array of values. As you see in my updated fiddle, checking and unchecking the boxes will insert or remove the appropriate value from the `self.properties` variable. This variable is an observable array.

Comment: Hi, I saw that it works but I need to bind it to jsonDirProperties and the checkbox value has to match the "propertyId". So for every checkbox checked there should be a new json object. I will send that json collection to server and map it to my object. Or do you recommend me another way?

Comment: Do you really need to roundtrip all that information? Can't you just send the self.properties array to the server?

Comment: You are totally right!!... I will do that. Right now Im getting the json string on the server but I will have to map it to a INT object list, do you know if I can send to server an array instead of json?

Comment: Yes, that should work. An array with just a bunch of strings is a valid JSON object as well. The checkbox value are always strings even if you put integers in the value, so you will have to do a bit of mapping on the server.

Comment: Right now this is one way (from client to server), but do you know how can I bind the checkboxes with the properties comming from server?

Comment: Look at the INPUT elements in my jsFiddle. Only the value attribute and inner text are different per row. Can you render the elements like this from the server side?